# How to provide a local font for a shiny app via bslib?

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

This works if I put inside my UI:

```
library(shiny)
 bslib::page_fluid(

      tags$style(HTML("@font-face {
    font-family: 'Hunger Games';
    src: url('www/Hunger Games.ttf') format('truetype');
  }"))
)
```

But this does not work:

```
library(shiny)
     bslib::page_fluid(
        theme = bs_theme(version = 5,
                       preset = "shiny",
                       heading_font = font_face(
                         family = 'Hunger Games',
                       src = "url('www/Hunger Games.ttf') format('truetype')"))
)
```

Comment: Have you tried without the `www` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes, same result. It works if I have the `tags` also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found by using the inspector Tools. The app is looking for a file `Hunger Games-0.4.7/Hunger Games.ttf`, in the **www** subfolder. So you have to put your file **Hunger Games.ttf** in **www/Hunger Games-0.4.7**, and don't write `www/` in `url`. The **0.4.7** is the version of the **sass** package.

This does not throw a 404 error:

```r
thm <- bs_theme(version = 5,
         preset = "shiny",
         heading_font = font_face(
           family = 'Hunger Games',
           src = "url('Hunger Games.ttf') format('truetype')"))
bs_theme_preview(thm)
```

---

## EDIT

The above does not work in Shiny (or does not work at all, not sure...).

Now I've found how to do with Shiny. You have to add a resource path, for example you create a ***fonts*** subfolder in which you put the ***ttf*** file, and you use the `addResourcePath` function. This function requires a prefix, I take `fonts` in the example below. Then you have to prefix the ***ttf*** file in `url`, like this: `url('/myprefix/myfontfile.ttf')`.

```r
library(bslib)
library(shiny)

addResourcePath("fonts", "./fonts") # the first 'fonts' is the prefix

thm <- bs_theme(
  version = 5,
  preset = "shiny",
  heading_font = font_face(
    family = "HungerGames",
    src = "url('/fonts/HungerGames.ttf') format('truetype')"
  )
)

ui <- page_fluid(
  theme = thm,
  title = "Hello",
  tags$h1("Test")
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output){})
```

(Note that I removed the white space in your font file name, because I feared it could cause another difficulty; I didn't try with the white space.)

Comment: I tried it but the rendered font is not `Hunger Games`. Shiny was only recognizing the font in `www` but not in the subfolder.

Comment: @umairdurrani Where are we supposed to see the heading font? In a `tags$h1`?

Comment: Yes, `h1` is what I use and it renders with `tags$style`.

Comment: @umairdurrani Please see my edit. It works! :-)